# PowerPivot - How to calculate trend by comparing two periods?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax, powerview

I'would like to create a KPI to compare results from two periods.

My data source looks like the following example :

```
User | NB sales | Date
Bob  | 10       | 01/01/2014
Tim  | 20       | 01/01/2014
Bob  | 5        | 01/02/2014
...
```

So I would like to compare the number of sales for the current to the previous week.
However I don't know how to process it.

```
= CALCULATE(SUM('Sales [Nb Sales]'), WEEKNUM('Sales [Date]') = )
```

I seen on Microsoft help there is a DAX function ParallelPeriod() to compare periods but I don't know if I should use it.

Should I use the formula as calculated column or as calculated value (bottom part).

This KPI should indicate if an employee sold more or less products than the previous week.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I would probably handle this in 3 measures:

```
[Sales] = SUM(Sales[Nb Sales])
[Sales Prior Week] = CALCULATE([Sales], DATEADD(Sales[Date], -7, Day))
[Sales WOW] = ([Sales] / [Sales Prior Week])-1
```

You should really be using a separate, linked, date table for all the calendar stuff!